# My SDL application not responding

Tags: sdl

I have a problem with SDL. When i run the following code it is not responding. I have .bmp in same folder as the executable file.Is problem in code or where.....?

```
  #include "SDL/SDL.h"

 int main( int argc, char* args[] )
 {
   SDL_Surface* robot = NULL;
   SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
   SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
   screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );
   robot = SDL_LoadBMP( "robot.bmp" );
   SDL_BlitSurface( robot, NULL, screen, NULL );
   SDL_Flip( screen );
   SDL_Delay( 12*1000 );
   SDL_FreeSurface( robot );
   SDL_Quit();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: can you clarify not responding? does it show the image at "robot.bmp"?  is this image in the same directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ game loop example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029545/c-game-loop-example)

Comment: robot.bmp is in same directori it is in project... when i want to close it it display the program is not responding. If i run it like .exe it dont display image, if i debug and run it in code blocks it display it. But in both case if i click on screen or want to close it, it dispaly the program is not responding.

Comment: look at the reply on the link i posted in the comment above

Comment: It's stil not responding?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SDL_Delay( 12*1000 );` will halt the current thread for 12 seconds. The issue is that the thread which is halted is the "video" thread, the one in charge of displaying  your image. After 12 secons the window will close and the program will exit.

In order to see the image and exit at will, you need to wait on a specific event of your choice like a keyboard event. See [here how to make basic event loop](http://interhacker.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/chapter-3-the-sdl-event-loop/) with SDL.